# Simple_List_item_checked How to keep the checkmark after activity change

Tags: java, android

I'm making an GroceryList app i want my grocerylist to be divised by department (Bakery, Fruit, Meat, etc).
Right now i did the creation of the list so im able to populate a external storage file and retrive the information by department.

When a display let say the fruit list view i'm using the layout Simple_list_item_checked so i can check any item in my list.Everything is working fine until a press the previous button on my phne and then i click on the button to go back to my fruit list view my item are not checked anymore.

I tried to use onSaveinstance/onRestore method  with bundle but it didnt work.
I also read about shared preference but i'm not sure its what i need and since i'm using Simple_list_item_checked i dont know how to use it.

```
public class FruitList_Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private ListView fruitsList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFruit;
private Button btn_Delete;
private Button btn_SelectAll;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_fruit_list_);




    fruitsList = findViewById(R.id.list_Fruits);
    fruitsList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    btn_Delete = findViewById (R.id.btn_delete);
    CreateActivity.itemsFruit = FileHelper.readData(this);

    adapterFruit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, CreateActivity.itemsFruit);
    fruitsList.setAdapter(adapterFruit);




    /*Remove items*/
    btn_Delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = fruitsList.getCheckedItemPositions();
            int itemCount = fruitsList.getCount();

            for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                    fruitsList.setItemChecked(i,true);
                    adapterFruit.remove(CreateActivity.itemsFruit.get(i));
                    FileHelper.writeData(CreateActivity.itemsFruit, FruitList_Activity.this );

                }
            }

            adapterFruit.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });



}
}
```

I'm just starting with java so please i would like some advise and clear instruction.

Answer (score 0):

In the `onResume` method you could set your adapter as follows to populate your list when you return.

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    adapterFruit = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, CreateActivity.itemsFruit);
    fruitsList.setAdapter(adapterFruit);
}
```

You might also want to update you `configChanges` in you manifest to stop the layout from changing due to other event (like orientation). In the `<application` tag:

```
<activity android:name=".FruitList_Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize"/>
```

Comment: I've read about the onResume method but i dont understand where it save the states of my checkmark ?

Comment: It doesn't save the state. It will be called when you revisit the `Activity` and you just set the list again like you would in `onCreate`

Comment: if i just set the list again like i would in onCreate it will not keep my item that were checked before i hit the previous button ? Sorry but i'm missing somehting and i would like to understand.

Comment: I think when you leave an activity you lose your variables. Then when you come back to the activity `onResume` is called and that's where you can set it again. That's a really poor description of what actually happens and I could even be wrong but that's my understanding of it. Hope this helps